# Has anyone ever run into issues re-entering Poland under the US/Polish bilateral agreement?

Tags: us-citizens, poland

I am a US citizen residing in Poland under the US/Polish [bilateral agreement](https://www.strazgraniczna.pl/pl/cudzoziemcy/najczesciej-zadawane-py/5012,15-Jestem-obywatelem-Stanow-Zjednoczonych-Ameryki-USA-jak-mam-obliczyc-dlugosc-d.html). I've been flying to the UK every 90 days and flying back with no problems so far since November of last year. Has anyone else leveraged this bilateral agreement and been denied entry or heard of any cases where someone was denied entry?

As requested, here are my passport stamps:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

- I entered Germany on November 13, 2022
- I exited Poland and flew to the US on February 5, 2023
- I re-entered Poland in Warsaw on March 5, 2023
- I exited Poland and flew to London from Gdańsk on May 5, 2023
- I re-entered Poland in Poznań on May 7, 2023
- I exited Poland and flew to the US on July 8, 2023
- I re-entered Poland in Warsaw on July 23, 2023

Comment: This has often been a topic, but you are the first to have claimed to have done this. You are also the first to provide a link from the polish **Border Guard Service** stating how the *exchange of notes of April 4, 1991* [not bilateral agreement] is being interpreted by the Ministry of Foreign Affairs and adopted by the Border Guard. If possible add an image of the polish/uk stamps showing that you were allowed to return to poland despite the fact that the 90 days were exceeded.

Comment: I have updated my post with photos and a log.

Comment: I may be confused, but what is the question here?  Is it that you are concerned that you will be refused entry to Poland at some point, and you are looking for anecdotes that support or negate that concern?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am wondering if anyone has had any issues at border crossing while leveraging the agreement.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39649/us-citizen-90-180-schengen-stay-bilateral-agreements-w-poland-denmark-etc

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why Mark Johnson says you're the first to do this (as if he knows the goings-on of every human on the planet).  This was common practice among expats for some time.

I've never heard of it being denied, HOWEVER, I've heard the most stamps you start to rack up like that, the more questions you may face upon re-entry.  At a certain point, as entry is ALWAYS, in practicality, at the discretion of the immigration official deciding whether or not to stamp you, I would think about getting residency.

As you're about the one-year mark on "leveraging" this, I'd say you MAY start to face additional questions on a subsequent re-entry (if they bother to check, but as it appears all your stamps are grouped in your passport, wouldn't be difficult to notice).

I've been "nomadic" over five years, and in my experience, the general rule of thumb is unless you are already planning travel every few months, after about a year, you may want to consider just getting residency.  It will save you hassle, in the long-run.

Comment: This has often been a topic **on this site**, ...